# How to change the branch being built in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-7.0, teamcity-9.1

How do I change the branch being built in TeamCity. It seems like the master is the only branch I can use:

[image: Please click this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to TeamCity.

I click on project which will show me my repository.

[image]

Clicking on both the drop down arrows shows me the branches of my repository

[image]

Click on the branch you want to build. Then you can run the build
[image]